# Sitecore workflow publish action parameters

Tags: sitecore, publish, sitecore-workflow

We have workflows enabled for majority of our content in Sitecore. We are using the auto-publish feature available after an item gets into the Final state of the workflow. Our implementation partner has enabled 3 parameters for this publish action -

- alllanguages=1
- related=1
- deep=1

I understand that deep publishes only the children of the item that the workflow is on. I also understand that related will publish all related images, items are linked via the link manager functionality. But I do not understand what the alllanguages parameter is for. Does this publish the item in the workflow in all available languages? Also, would it publish all children and related items in all available languages as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 6 parameters boolean, 1 or 0

With allanguages, related and deep, it publish the current item and childeren and related items in all languages so also the childeren and related are published in all languages.

See this article [auto-publish-workflow-action-updates](http://www.sitecore.net/nl-nl/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/reinnovations/posts/2014/03/auto-publish-workflow-action-updates.aspx)

This are the language options:

"alllanguages" - controls whether current item will be published in all languages that exist in source database. Possible values: "1" - current item will be published in all languages that exist in source database; all other values - code uses values of other parameters to determine languages in which current item will be published.

"languages" - comma (,) separated list of languages in which current item will be published.

"itemlanguage" - controls whether current item will be published in its current language. Possible values: "1" - current item will be published in its current language; "0" - current item will not be published in its current language; all other values - current item will published in its current language. Note that even if value of this parameter is "0", current item will still be published in its current language if current language of the item is in "languages" list.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore has versions and languages for each item; My assumption (without seeing the implementation) would be it publishes all (available) versions of said items. That is to say, if you only had an `en-US` language version, you wouldn't necessarily get an `es-SP` too (unless part of your workflow is a language translation).